# Cannot set UICollectionViewFlowLayout headerReferenceSize

Tags: ios

I get the following when setting the layout.headerReferenceSize

```
Assertion failure in -[HLEventCollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:],
```

The crash happens even before the dataSource is set. The collectionView is frame is set for the viewControllers bounds. The flowLayout has no properties set except for the headerReferenceSize.

code sample:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 30.0f);

UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[self.view addSubview:collectionView];
```

}

It happens regardless of if I set the dataSource or not.

Comment: How about you post the code where you're trying to set it. Have you declared `<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>` ?